# catch error for bad json format thrown by express.json() middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I am getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 59` error in html format when format of json data is not valid.
I don't know why it is giving me html instead of error object.
I have set my header like below.

```
//header middlewares
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    next();
  });
```

I want to catch the error and send a message in below format.

```
{ 
  "status":404,
  "message":Unexpected string in JSON at position 59
}
```

Here is the error that I get.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 59<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at JSON.parse (&lt;anonymous&gt;)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (C:\Users\mydirectory\auth\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js: 89: 19)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\mydirectory\auth\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js: 121: 18<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at invokeCallback (C:\Users\mydirectory\auth\node_modules\raw-body\index.js: 224: 16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done (C:\Users\my-directory\auth\node_modules\raw-body\index.js: 213: 7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\mydirectory\auth\node_modules\raw-body\index.js: 273: 7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js: 203: 15)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js: 1145: 12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js: 63: 19)</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried catching this error.

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err instanceof SyntaxError && err.status === 400 && 'body' in err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(400).send(err); // Bad request
    }
    next();
});
```

But the response that I get now is like below.

```
{
    "expose": true,
    "statusCode": 400,
    "status": 400,
    "body": "{\n\t\"username\":\n}",
    "type": "entity.parse.failed"
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I posted this question on expressjs github repo, and I got a nice and reasonable solution.

> If you want that specific response, that is what you need to send in your error handler instead of the err object itself.

```
 app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err instanceof SyntaxError && err.status === 400 && 'body' in err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(400).send({ status: 400, message: err.message }); // Bad request
    }
    next();
});
```

Now I am able to send the desired response.

```
{
   "status": 400,
   "message": "Unexpected string in JSON at position 37"
}
```

[Link to issue](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/4065)

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. This is a significant security issue to boot as it exposes your directory structure.

Comment: typo 404=>400 in your sample, anyway thanks, very useful!

Answer (score 4):

You will have to handle parsing error separately like below:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err instanceof SyntaxError && err.status === 400 && 'body' in err) {
        if (err.type === 'entity.parse.failed') {
            let data = req.body || req.query;
            try {
                JSON.parse(data); // <-- reproduce error in order to catch it
            } catch (error) {
                // get the first line of error which is "SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 59"
                let message = error.toString().split("\n")[0];
                return res.status(400).send({ status: 400, message: message }); // Bad request
            }
        }            
        else return res.status(400).send(err); // Bad request
    }
    next();
});
```

Comment: This is bad to reproduce the error as this is just unnecessary code.

Comment: the second if does not do anything in my case. can you explain why you put it there?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an object to store the error details you want and return those as json...

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err instanceof SyntaxError && err.status === 400 && 'body' in err) {
        let formattedError = {
          status: err.statusCode,
          message: err.message
        }
        return res.status(err.statusCode).json(formattedError); // Bad request
    }
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to catch all errors thrown by body-parsr for example
**entity.too.large** or **encoding.unsupported**

just place this middleware right after your body-parser initialization

```
$ npm i express-body-parser-error-handler
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-body-parser-error-handler

for example:

```
const bodyParserErrorHandler = require('express-body-parser-error-handler')
const { urlencoded, json } = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
router.route('/').get(function (req, res) {
    return res.json({message:""});
});

// body parser initilization
app.use('/', json({limit: '250'}));

// body parser error handler
app.use(bodyParserErrorHandler());
app.use(router);
...
```