# How can I handle json-parse errors in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

My problem seems to be fairly simple and common, but nevertheless I can't seem to find anything about it after hours of research:

I want to retrieve JSON-data in Node.js via http-POST using Express. To keep it simple, I want to use the app.use(express.json()); function (see code).

When the JSON-data is correct JSON-syntax, everything works fine, but when there is a syntax error in the JSON-data, it handles the error on its own, automatically replying to the client and logging a huge error message on the console.
What I'd like to do is to handle the error the way I want, but I'm not sure how I can manage to do that.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    // do something with the retreived JSON-data
});
```

I would be very thankful if somebody could give me a tip/solution! :)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58134287/catch-error-for-bad-json-format-thrown-by-express-json-middleware

Comment: Does this answer your question? [catch error for bad json format thrown by express.json() middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58134287/catch-error-for-bad-json-format-thrown-by-express-json-middleware)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could handle malformed JSON errors using this, as the error is an instance of `SyntaxError`

```js
app.use((error, request, response, next) => {
    if (error instanceof SyntaxError)
        response.status(404).send('your error message');
    else 
        next();
});
```