# Why is my express middleware not logging json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

I am trying to make my own version of the burp collaborator (or requestbin). I want to log all the requests that are made to 127.0.0.1:3000

I wrote this code but it is not working. A morgan middleware that store the requests in a global variable.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var app = express();
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

global.requestlogs = [];
const logRequest = (req, res, next) => {
  const now = new Date();
  if ((req.url !== '/logs') && (req.url !== '/craft')) {
    let body = '';
    req.on('data', chunk => {
      body += chunk.toString();
    }).on('end', () => {
      let to_log_Body = body;
      const requestInfo = {
        method: req.method,
        url: req.url,
        ip: req.ip,
        headers: req.headers,
        body: to_log_Body
      };
      console.log(body);
      requestlogs.unshift({now: now, request: requestInfo, expanded: false});
    });
  }
  next();
};
```

I run my express app. When I do:

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/echo/post/json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"productId": 123456, "quantity": 100}'
```

Nothing is logged in my app.

When I do:

```
curl -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:3000/echo/post/json -H "Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8" -d 'productId=123456&s=124}{|'
```

Everything works.

When I do:

```
curl -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1:3000/echo/post/json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"productId": 123456, "quantity": 100'
```

I get a syntax error:

```
<h1>Expected &#39;,&#39; or &#39;}&#39; after property value in JSON at position 37</h1>
<h2>400</h2>
<pre>SyntaxError: Expected &#39;,&#39; or &#39;}&#39; after property value in JSON at position 37
    at JSON.parse (&lt;anonymous&gt;)
...
```

I do not understand why json is treated differently. I am just treating everything as a steam ... Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: The JSON you are sending is malformed, you are missing the closing curly bracket ^^

Comment: I know, I want it to be logged even with the error :-)

Comment: Sorry now I got what you want! Then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58134287/catch-error-for-bad-json-format-thrown-by-express-json-middleware) is what you are looking for ^^